# MySQL: How can you update all NULL/blank values in return within the query?

Tags: mysql, null

Is there a way to update any return values in MySQL that come back as either NULL or blank to "Unknown" or any value? My NULLs and blanks exist because I'm joining quite a few tables together and sometimes records exist but are blank and sometimes records don't exist in the other tables at all.

I would prefer not to update the original table because I don't save my result each time I run the query -- I just copy and paste the return into Excel before I send out the report.

Basically, it's just getting annoying sending this out multiple times a day and after pasting into Excel hitting Ctrl+F and replacing anywhere that says "NULL" with "Unknown" and then doing it again to replace any blank cell with "Unknown."

After looking around, I found `IFNULL` which obviously works if it's NULL but not blank -- but (1) it would be great to not have to wrap every part of my SELECT statement with `IFNULL`s if possible and (2) use something to encompass the blanks as well.

Just hoping there's something that I could put at the end of the query or something that I can't find. But it might just not exist within the way I'm doing it. I don't think this question needs code or schema because of the general-ness of it, but I'm certainly happy to get more specific if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: The `CASE` expression is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all of the columns that could be null in a case statement that checks if any of them are null or blank before returning them.

For example:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN firsttable.column1 IS NULL or firsttable.column1 = '' THEN 'Unknown' ELSE firsttable.column1 END AS firsttable.column1
    CASE WHEN firsttable.column2 IS NULL or firsttable.column2 = '' THEN 'Unknown' ELSE firsttable.column2 END AS firsttable.column2
    CASE WHEN secondtable.column1 IS NULL or secondtable.column1 = '' THEN 'Unknown' ELSE secondtable.column1 END AS firsttable.column1
    CASE WHEN secondtable.column2 IS NULL or secondtable.column1 = '' THEN 'Unknown' ELSE secondtable.column2 END AS firsttable.column2
FROM
    firsttable,
    secondtable
WHERE
    firsttable.id = secondtable.firsttableid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF in combination with COALESCE:

```
SET @val := '';
select IF(COALESCE(@val,'')='','Unknown',@val);
```

Returns 'Unknown', the same will returns for NULL. Any other value will be returned:

```
SET @val := 'test';
select IF(COALESCE(@val,'')='','Unknown',@val);
```

Returns 'test'.

Trick is in [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) - it returns first non-NULL value, so COALESCE(NULL,'') will return '' and COALESCE('','') will return '' too. You can replace variable @val with any column from table or view etc.